# how set width for each new line in draw view in apple swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use a slider to set line width for the lines I draw in drawRect. Right now, the slider changes the width of every line. Instead, I'd like it to change just a single line. How can I go about doing this?

Here's my `drawRect` method, where I use the line width:

```
var lineW: CGFloat = 5

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect){
    var context  = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound)

      for line in lines{
            CGContextBeginPath(context)
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineW)
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, line.start.x, line.start.y)
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line.end.x, line.end.y)
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, line.color.CGColor)
            CGContextStrokePath(context)            
        }     
}
```

Comment: You should add the line width to the line object.

Comment: thanx  now its working which i want